# Understanding update method in scala

Tags: scala, jvm

I can understand the `apply` method in scala which basically is applying a function to a value. In many cases this is used as a form of constructor.

Let's assume that `list` is a map. An example would be `def apply(id : Int) = list(id)`, where it gets the given element from the list.

I also came across the example of the update method as

`def update(id:Int,name:String) = list = list + (id -> name)`.

I can understand what this does i.e it updates/adds a key value pair in the list. What I cannot understand is the method contains two `=` symbols, one after the method definition and one which after list which defines what the method actually does `list + (id -> name)`.

What is the need for two `=` signs? How is one different from one another? I know that after the `=` sign the method body starts, but this is confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view it as:

```
def update(id: Int, name: String): Unit = {
  // perform update on 'list'
  list = list + (id -> name)
  // return empty (Unit) value
}
```

Comment: So it is just a shorthand notation? That is new. Thanks for pointing it out. Is there any specific name for this in documentation or something?

Comment: I don't have the link, perhaps I'll search for it later. But yes, this is the shorthand notation. You can use both versions interchangeably, both for methods and values. Just as you can have a method `def foo() = 42`, you can also have a value `val myInteger = { doSomeStuff(); 42 }` (the last computed value will be assigned)

Answer (score 1):

The first `=` is what separates the method signature

```
def update(id: Int,name: String)
```

from its definition

```
list = list + (id -> name)
```

The `=` in the definition is an assignment operation, where the expression on the right of the `=` is evaluated and assigned to the object on the left.